# Trouble determining the pattern for NSRegularExpression...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

i am relatively new to NSRegularExpression and just can't come up with a pattern to find a string within a string.... 
here is the string...

```
#@$294@001@[12345-678[123-456-7@15665@2
```

I want to extract the string..

`@001@[12345-678[123-456-7@`

for more info I know that there will be 3 digits(like `001`) between two `@` 's and 20 characters between the last two `@` 's..

I have tried n number of combinations but nothing seem to work. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
@[0-9]{3}@.{20}@
```

If you know that the 20 characters will always consist of digits, `[` and `-`, your pattern would become:

```
@[0-9]{3}@[0-9\[\-]{20}@
```

Be careful with the backslashes: When you use create the pattern with a string literal (`@"..."`), you need to add an extra backslash before each backslash.

Comment: what does the "." (dot signify..?)

Comment: The dot matches any character, you might want to use a more specific pattern, if you know that it will always be digits, `[` and `-`.

Comment: I don't believe you have to escape a left bracket ('[') within a bracket expression.  Likewise, you don't have to escape a dash ('-') if it's the first character in a bracket expression.

Comment: I think you're right, it doesn't hurt though and I actually find it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.. customized it to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can test NSRegularExpression patterns without recompiling each time by using RegexTester https://github.com/liyanage/regextester